# How can I unit test classes that read input in Java?

Tags: java, junit, io

How is it possible to run tests against a class that reads from System.in for user input?

For example:

```
private int getUserInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What's ya input? [1-3]: ");
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

I've thought maybe subclassing the main class and overridding getUserInput to feed back scripted answers. Though this won't work if you need to read System.out to decide the input.

I spent a few hours looking up Threads however couldn't figure out how to use them for this either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you *can* replace `System.in` using `System.setIn()` but I would not favour that approach.  Setting global state always makes your tests a bit more fragile and non-transparent.

Instead you should really try to break the dependency, for example by injecting the `InputStream` that you want to read from into your class through the class' constructor.  Once you do that, when you unit test it you can pass in your own `InputStream` that reads from static data, and in your production code you can inject `System.in`.

Comment: +1 for dependency injection. Once you understand this you really look at object design differently.

Comment: Reading global [ambient] state is always a bad design. One of the many impacts that has is to make testing poorer. / "Injecting" is a bit of a pointless term. It's just using constructors in the way that they are supposed to be used. Access to the input object is *endowed*.

Comment: @Tom: I said "injecting" because this is a form of dependency injection.  There are other forms of dependency injection that do not involve passing the dependency through the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Either put your references to System.in and System.out to variables or to result values of methods that you can override in your test (by other streams, like ByteArrayInput/OutputStream, or (if that is not possible) use System.setOut and System.setIn to replace the default streams, run your test, validate the output and set them back.

Comment: How can you reset System.in after assigning it a different value?

Comment: `PrintStream oldSystemIn = System.in; System.setIn(`...`); `...`; System.setIn(oldSystemIn);` - preferrably in a try...finally block.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [Mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) objects that imitates user input.